# Tor "saveconf" command returns error message always

Tags: tor, rc

```
$telnet localhost 9051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
authenticate "xxxxxxx"
250 OK
getconf controlport
250 ControlPort=9051
resetconf controlport
250 OK
getconf controlport
250 ControlPort
setconf controlport=9051
250 OK
saveconf
551 Unable to write configuration to disk.
setconf nickname=testnickname
250 OK
saveconf
551 Unable to write configuration to disk.
```

Whenever I try to execute the `saveconf` command it returns an error. I checked the torrc file. It is not getting saved in that too. What could be the reason? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the tor user have write permission to its torrc location? Permission gotcha would be the first thing I'd suspect. You can get the location with 'GETINFO config-file'.

Comment: Only this user and sudo are there in the system. I hope sudo is not necessary to execute saveconf while accessing control port.

Comment: No, I meant the *tor process*. When you run SAVECONF the tor process tries to write to disk, so if it doesn't have write permissions it can fail like this.

Comment: I am not sure about this. How can I give write permission for tor process?

Comment: Run 'GETINFO config-file' to get its location on disk, then run 'ls -l /that/path' to get its permissions. Quick search for file permissions should help you from there.

Comment: I will give a try and come back :)`